# Filled circular sections in polar axis, tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, polarplot

I would like to draw **and fill** circular sections in a polar axis, with 0 deg in correspondence of the current vertical axis, as in the first example picture.

[image]

Unfortunately I couldn't find any similar example, so I'm asking here.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}
    % ....
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as pure `tikz` picture:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% axis
\draw[->]   (-3,0.0) -- (3.5,0) node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[->]   (0,-0.5) -- (0.0,3) node[below left] {$y$};
\draw       (-5:2) arc (-5:185:2);
% ticks
\foreach \angle in {90, 60, ...,-90}
    \draw (90+\angle:1.9) -- (90+\angle:2)
                        ++ (90+\angle:0.4)
        node[fill=white, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt] {$\angle$};
% sectors
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[yellow]   (0,0) -- (135:2) arc(135:60:2) -- cycle;
\fill[orange]   (0,0) -- (105:2) arc(105:75:2) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's amazing, it is exactly was I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: Any idea on how to invert the angle signs? I mean positive angles to the right and negative to the left. I've tried to change the code in any possible way, but the result is always the same. Thanks in advance!

Comment: this should be simple :-) : `\foreach \angle in {-90, -60, ...,90}
    \draw (90+\angle:1.9) -- (90+\angle:2)
                        ++ (90+\angle:0.4)
        node[fill=white, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt] {$\angle$};`

Comment: Thank you again for you patience! That's the first thing I had tried, but apparently this doesn't change the result!